# Virtual Functions and Polymorphism - Code Explanation

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class GrandParent {
 public:
      int variable1;
      static int variable2;
      int virtual show() { return 10; }
};

int GrandParent :: variable2 = 9;

class Parent1 : public virtual GrandParent {
 public:
      int show() { return 1; }  
};

class Parent2 : public virtual GrandParent {
 public:
      int show() { return 9; }  
};

class Child : public Parent1, public Parent2 {
 public:
      int variable1;
      Child(){variable1 = 10; GrandParent::variable2 = 3;}
      int show() { return 7; }  
};

int main() {
      GrandParent *objGrand = new Child();
      GrandParent *objGrand1 = new Parent1();
      Parent2 *objP = new Child();
      Child *objChild = new Child();
      int a = (objGrand->show())*(objP->show())*(objChild->show())*(objGrand1->show());
      int b = (objGrand->variable1)*(objP->variable1)*(objChild->variable1);
      int c = (objGrand->variable2)*(objP->variable2)*(objChild->variable2);

      cout << a + b * c << endl;
      return 0;
}
```

Can someone please help me understand why (objGrand->variable1) = 0 & (objP->variable1) = 0 and not 10?
This is a part of an online course I am doing. They posted the solution and an explanation. However, I did not find their explanation convincing so needed some help.

Comment: What makes you think `objGrand->variable1 = 0`? When I do `cout << objGrand->variable1` I get a random number, because `GrandParent::variable1` has never been initialized.

Comment: Some objects have more than one variable with the same name (but possibly different values). Not the best idea, because people get confused (like you have noticed).

Comment: @BoPersson I think that's the point of the lesson, to show how variable shadowing and virtual function inheritance works.

Comment: This program has undefined behavior, because it uses the value (does an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on) the `variable1` subobject of the `GrandParent` base, which was never initialized and therefore has an indeterminate value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Child` re-declares the member variable `variable1`. This gives this class its own variable with that name, shadowing the variable inherited from the `GrandParent` class. So when its constructor does:

```
variable1 = 10;
```

it's assigning to `Child::variable1`, not `GrandParent::variable1`.

Member variables aren't accessed virtually, this is only done for `virtual` member functions. So if you then use

```
objGrand->variable1
```

it refers to `GrandParent::variable1`, because `objGrand` is `GrandParent*`, even though `objGrand` points to a `Child` object. Since `GrandParent` has no constructor that initializes `variable1`, this is uninitialized, not `0`, and using it results in undefined behavior.

To get `Child::variable1` you need to downcast it:

```
dynamic_cast<Child*>(objGrand)->variable1
```

The same is true for `objP` for the same reasons.

Comment: Summed up perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @RejoyMathews since you find this to be a perfect summary, you should mark the answer as accepted.